# High Volume of API Errors

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook Developer alert says that:

> In the last three hours 100% of the calls to the method POST
>   /achievements resulted in errors.

```
Error Code: 100 Error Description:
Invalid parameter Error Count: 4,708
```

But we haven't changed the code in 4 or 5 months.  What could be the problem?  As I see it there is no additional parameter added to facebook achievements.

Comment: can you share the code you used to make the calls to achievements please.

Answer (score 1):

It was because of some of the users did not grant the `publish_actions` permission.  Granting this permission solved the problem.